# Does AgensGraph support sharding?

Tags: distributed, sharding, agens-graph

I'm using AgensGraph Community edition on my server. 
And I have a question.
Does AgensGraph support sharding? 
If not, how does AgensGraph support a distributed environment? 
Or.. is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharding support comes with PostgreSQL 11 whereas AgensGraph is currently a fork off 10.4 that does not support sharding.

PostgreSQL is not natively distributed before sharding in 11. Here's a good article https://www.quora.com/Is-PostgreSQL-a-distributed-and-scalable-database

The Enterprise edition (license fee applies) of AG supports HA via Stolon.

Enterprise edition https://bitnine.net/agensgraph-2-1-0-enterprise-linux/
AgensGraph HA via Stolon https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnine/stolon/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope 11.x version is applied with AgensGraph soon.